# ruby: accessing caller variables from declared obj instance

Tags: ruby, variables

```
class X
end
class A
    def get_it
      puts @the_variable
    end
end

class B
  def init_it
     @the_variable = X.new
     a = A.new
  end
end
```

In the above code I want methods of Class A to access the instance of X instantiated in B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`Object#instance_variable_set`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001029):

```
class B
  def init_it
     @the_variable = X.new
     a = A.new
     a.instance_variable_set(:@the_variable, @the_variable) 
 end
end
```